# Return value order is changes when send HashMap in Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I am using **Spring** as backend and **Ajax** to Get and Post data. In my controller, I return **HashMap**. Everything is working fine. But when I receive data in javascript file the data order is changing. What am I doing wrong?

For example when I send

```
map.put("name","aaa");
map.put("name","bbb");
map.put("name","ccc");
```

in js file I get different order like ccc,aaa,bbb. Changed order is always same. It is not random.

Here are some code I am using.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/history", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, myModel> getHistory() {

    Map<String, ChatModel> userInfo = md.getUserInfo(userId);

    return userInfo;
}
```

Get method

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        type : "GET",
        url : "../Spring4MVCHelloWord/history/",
        dataType : 'json',   
        success: function(data){

            displayHistory(data);
        },

         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(xhr);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a **`LinkedHashMap`** instead. A `LinkedHashMap` will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map. If performance is something you desire and you can do away with ordering, then go for a HashMap.